# How to integrate webr quarto html output into an existing webpage?

Tags: html, r, quarto, quarto-webr, webr

I'm a somewhat experienced R coder, but I have very little knowledge in the HTML world. I've followed the instructions provided [here](https://quarto-webr.thecoatlessprofessor.com/qwebr-first-steps.html) to create a Webr-based Quarto document. It renders the html and runs the code when the html doc is opened in my browser locally.

I would like to integrate these Webr-quarto documents in my university learning page. Could anybody advise how to do this?

I have tried embedding the html output directly, but it does not run and remains "Loading" (screenshot attached).

Code looks like this:

````
---
title: "webr_exercises"
format: html
engine: knitr
resources:
  - webr-serviceworker.js
  - webr-worker.js
filters: 
  - webr
webr:
  packages: ['ggplot2', 'dplyr']

---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

```{webr-r}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Comment: Could you include the screenshot in your post? It's not there. Also, what happens is you include `embed-resources: true` under the `html` key?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using service worker option with webR. (Especially on an LMS.)

Instead, please use `"automatic"`, which will default into either `post-message` or `shared-array-buffer` ([Documentation](https://quarto-webr.thecoatlessprofessor.com/qwebr-communication-channels.html#sec-automatic)). The latter communication channel does require header changes regarding how the LMS is serving the document.

Next, I would suggest using Quarto HTML's [`embed-resources`](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/html.html#links) option to directly embed `webr.mjs`, Monaco Editor, and FontAwesome that are used by the `{quarto-webr}` extension.

The following Quarto HTML document with these changes should work:

````
---
title: "webR Document"
format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true
engine: knitr
webr:
  packages: ['ggplot2', 'dplyr']
filters:
  - webr
---

Sample interactive cell

```{webr-r}
plot(pressure)
```
````

From there, you should be able to upload just the `.html` file. Without the `embed-resources` option, you would need to upload the `.html` file and the `*_files` folder contents to ensure all resources would be available.

For more issues, you may want to raise this as an issue on the project repository:

https://github.com/coatless/quarto-webr/issues